# 500 error when .htaccess authetication added

Tags: php, .htaccess, configuration, server

A misconfiguration on the server caused a hiccup. Check the server logs, fix the problem, then try again.

This error is displayed only after I add this authentication part to my .htaccess...If I remove this part it shows the admin area without authentication....Please can anyone point out whether there is any syntax error...

```
<FilesMatch "admin">
    AuthUserFile "/home6/zeewatch/public_html/ecole-de-paris-fr//httpd.www/mu/.htpasswd
    AuthGroupFile /dev/null
    AuthName "admin"
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<FilesMatch "admin">
AuthName "Admin Panel"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /path/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

and what this?

```
ecole-de-paris-fr//httpd.www/mu/.htpasswd
```

you have "//" on the path, make it one forward slash

Comment: tried both of your suggestions...still it made no difference

Comment: there is an error in config, the error needs to be resolved in order to make it work. try to debug it. when there's syntax errors it throws misconfiguration" message. Try to post more elaborate description of your issue.